# Looping through Subfolders and export all ppt files to pdf in another folder [VBA]

Tags: vba

I'm looking for a VBA code to loop through all subfolders of my foldfolder, export each Powerpoint files which begin with "EN" in these subfolders to a pdf file, this new pdf files should be saved in another folder.
Thank you for your help.

---

```
  'It's VBA code that i tried to make 
 Sub loopthrough () 

     Dim folder As Object
     Dim fo As String
     Dim SubFolders As Object
     Dim CurrFile As Object
     Dim foldest As String
     Dim Chemin As String 'path'
     Dim fichier As String 'file'


    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fo = "C:\Users\samiess\Desktop\resu\"
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(fo)
    Set SubFolders = folder.SubFolders

     Dim ppAPP As PowerPoint.Application, ppPres As 
     PowerPoint.Presentation
     Set ppAPP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

     AppActivate Application.Caption

     foldest = "C:\Users\samiess\Desktop\resu\EN\"


     For Each SubFolders In SubFolders

     Set CurrFile = SubFolders.Files

     For Each CurrFile In CurrFile

     If CurrFile Like "*EN*" Then

    chemin = CurrFile
    fichier = Dir(chemin)

    End If


       Next

    Do While Len(fichier) > 0

   Set ppPres = ppAPP.Presentations.Open(fo & fichier)

   ppPres.ExportAsFixedFormat foldest & chemin,_ 
   FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF

   ppPres.Close
   fichier = Dir()

   Loop
   Next
  End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following piece of code to create an array with all files names you need. Sorry for the author, but I don't know who it is. (not me anyway).

```
Private Function RFilesList(fileMask As String) As Variant
'recursive file list
'returns an array with full filenames, including subfolders
'fileMask must include folder and file mask, like this: "c:\test\*.xl*"
    RFilesList = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c Dir """ & fileMask & """ /s/b").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)
End Function
```